# TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len() i cant find problem

Tags: python, django

i get TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len in django admin

models

models.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Products(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    default_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', blank=False)
    stock = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(ProductBrand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    createAt = date.jDateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    small_description = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, )
    variableProduct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, default=False, blank=True)
    productTags = models.ManyToManyField(ProductTags, default=False, blank=True)

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username
```

admin.py

```
class ProductsModelView(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'dir': 'rtl', })},
    }
    model = Products
    list_display = ('name', 'id', 'username')
admin.site.register(Products, ProductsModelView)
```

Error

```
TypeError at /admin/products/products/add/
object of type 'bool' has no len()
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.199:8000/admin/products/products/add/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
object of type 'bool' has no len()
Exception Location: E:\GOA\GOA\venv1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in has_changed, line 1354
Python Executable:  E:\GOA\GOA\venv1\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:    
['E:\\GOA\\GOA',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'E:\\GOA\\GOA\\venv1',
 'E:\\GOA\\GOA\\venv1\\lib\\site-packages',
 'E:\\GOA\\GOA\\venv1\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg']
Server time:    Wed, 24 Jun 2020 08:11:15 +0000
```

i try to save object in django admin and i get this error but create object with python shell has no problem

Comment: `ManyToManyField(Category, default=False` looks wrong. Try removing the defaults for the `ManyToManyField`s.

Comment: You have a boolean variable somewhere that gets passed to the len() function. Hard to tell from the code you posted.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks i checked for many times but I didn't understand

Comment: The data error is not really logical

Answer (score 0):

- auto_now - updates the value of field to current time and date every time the
  Model.save() is called.
- auto_now_add - updates the value with the time and date of creation of record.
- Any field with the auto_now attribute set will also inherit editable=False

change this

```
createAt = date.jDateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

to this

```
createAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)

OR

createAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
```